# Dynamically add overlay widgets

Tags: c++, qt

Is it possible to add dynamically new child widget to the parent?

I have the following code:

```
MyWidget : public QWidget
{
    MyWidget() : Qwidget() 
    {
        m_otherWidgets.push_back( new OtherWidget(this) ); // this will be painted
    }

    void addNew()
    {
        m_otherWidgets.push_back( new OtherWidget(this) ); // this will not be painted
    }

    std::vector<OtherWidget*> m_otherWidgets;
}

MyWidget bar(); // 1 other widget painted
bar.addNew(); // still only 1 other widget painted
```

Vector `m_otherWidgets` contains a list of child widgets. The problem is that it display only this child widgets, that were created during constructor time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more information I can only guess, but you probably forgot to call `show()`/`setVisible(true)`. Widgets added after the parent is shown are not always displayed.